# android java calling button from XML without getting NULL

Tags: java, android, button, null

I'm looking to call a few buttons but seem to be getting a NULL when trying to findbyviewid.  When I activate this activity, it crashes.

```
//CREATE INSTANCE OF GLOBAL - QUESTIONS/ANSWERS
Global global = Global.getInstance();

//CURRENT QUESTION
static int QQ = 0;

//CORRECT ANSWER COUNT
static int correctAnswers = 0;

//CREATE VARIABLE FOR TEXTVIEW/QUESTION
TextView textQuestion = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textQuestion);

//CREATE VARIABLES FOR BUTTONS/ANSWERS
Button buttonOne = (Button) findViewById(R.id.answerOne);
Button buttonTwo = (Button) findViewById(R.id.answerTwo);
Button buttonThree = (Button) findViewById(R.id.answerThree);
Button buttonFour = (Button) findViewById(R.id.answerFour);



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_practice_questions);


    setButtons();



    buttonOne.setOnClickListener(this);
    buttonTwo.setOnClickListener(this);
    buttonThree.setOnClickListener(this);
    buttonFour.setOnClickListener(this);



}





public void setButtons()
{

    //SET QUESTION STRING TO TEXTVIEW
    textQuestion.setText(global.getQ(QQ));

    //SET ANSWER STRINGS TO BUTTONS' TEXT
    buttonOne.setText(global.getA(QQ, 0));
    buttonTwo.setText(global.getA(QQ, 1));
    buttonThree.setText(global.getA(QQ, 2));
    buttonFour.setText(global.getA(QQ, 3));

}





@Override
public void onClick(View v)
{

    switch(v.getId())
    {
        case R.id.answerOne:
            checkAnswer(0, buttonOne);
            break;

        case R.id.answerTwo:
            checkAnswer(1, buttonTwo);
            break;

        case R.id.answerThree:
            checkAnswer(2, buttonThree);
            break;

        case R.id.answerFour:
            checkAnswer(3, buttonFour);
            break;

        default:
            break;
    }


}




public void checkAnswer(int a, Button b){

    //IF AN INCORRECT ANSWER WAS CHOSEN, MAKE THE BACKGROUND RED
    if(!global.getS(QQ, a))
    {
        b.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
    }
    else
    {
        //INCREMENT THE CORRECT ANSWER COUNTER
        correctAnswers++;
    }

    //SET BACKGROUND OF CORRECT BUTTON TO GREEN
    if(global.getS(QQ, 0))
    {
        buttonOne.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
    }
    else if(global.getS(QQ, 1))
    {
        buttonTwo.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
    }
    else if(global.getS(QQ, 2))
    {
        buttonThree.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
    }
    else if(global.getS(QQ, 3))
    {
        buttonFour.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
    }
    else
    {
        //IF NO ANSWER IS CORRECT, SET ALL TO BLUE
        buttonOne.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
        buttonTwo.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
        buttonThree.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
        buttonFour.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);

    }



    //MOVE TO NEXT QUESTION


}
```

I have 4 buttons in the XML file and want to be able to set the text to them, as well as run a listener for the set of buttons (answers to a question).  When one of the buttons is clicked, it should determine if it's the correct answer by pulling the status (true/false) and highlighting it red if it's incorrect.  It then highlights the correct answer green.

At least, some of this is in theory and I'm trying to test it out, but I can't start the activity without crashing.

Comment: call all findViewById methods inside onCreate method of Activity

Comment: Even after doing so, I'm not able to use the button variables in other methods of that class/activity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just how i said in comment, you should initialize it in `OnCreate` method, cause you set view layout for activity here. And before you do it, all `findViewById` returns null.

So, here your code:

```
Button buttonOne;
Button buttonTwo;
Button buttonThree;
Button buttonFour;
TextView textQuestion;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_practice_questions);

    buttonOne = (Button) findViewById(R.id.answerOne);
    buttonTwo = (Button) findViewById(R.id.answerTwo);
    buttonThree = (Button) findViewById(R.id.answerThree);
    buttonFour = (Button) findViewById(R.id.answerFour);
    textQuestion = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textQuestion);
    [...]
}
```

Comment: I was so focused on the buttons, I overlooked the TextView.  Thanks for taking the time to clarify something so simple.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not 100% sure but I think you can't do the findViewById at the instance constructions. You need to those inside onCreate() (after you called setContentView)

Comment: Got it.  Makes sense.  I'm not that Java efficient as you can tell.  But how would I declare a button so that I can use it throughout the activity, and initialize the button in the onCreate() method?  `Button buttonOne;` before onCreate() and `buttonOne = (Button) findViewById(R.id.answerOne);` on the inside on onCreate():???